# XML schema has data not contained in tags --?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse an unusual XML structure, as seen here.  Two self-closing tags are used to mark the start and end of the text.  Thus, the text is not within a tag division.

```
<article>
  <sec>
    <clause id="31"/>This says thirty-one <clause_end/>
    <clause id="32"/>This says thirty-two <clause_end/>
  </sec>
</article>
```

The legacy document is not well-suited for the discrete hierarchical requirements of XML and this schema attempts to work around the problems.

- Is it consistent with any sound implementation of XML?
- Do you have advice on how to apply an XML parser?

Keeping the original structure is desirable, but if the answers are No then I'll have to:

1. Make an alternative schema that tags the text normally: `<clause id="32"> text </clause>`.
2. Make the document well-formed by stripping out other tags that interfere with `<clause>`.  I'm pretty sure there's nothing I'll miss too badly.

By the way, I'd be happy to link to the live file *except* I'd rather not embarrass the developer, assuming this schema is as deviant as I think it is.  ;-)

### Based on answer from nine9ths...

- Is it consistent with any sound implementation of XML?
- . . . **Possibly**
- Do you have advice on how to apply an XML parser?
- . . . **Parse where you can, but at this level in the schema you must work strings.**

I might keep the existing structure but introduce one small enhancement:

```
<article>
  <sec>
    <clause id="31"/>This says thirty-one <clause_end id="31"/>
    <clause id="32"/>This says thirty-two <clause_end id="32"/>
  </sec>
</article>
```

Comment: If you're following my suggesting of pairing the `clause_start` and `clasue_end` with an ID reference, I'd recommend that the `clause_end/@id` be something else like `clause_end/@clause_start_id` (maybe a something a bit more concise) for semantic consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely precedent for this kind of structure in other schema for example see [`milestone-start`](http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/archiving/tag-library/3.0/n-dae0.html) and [`milestone-end`](http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/archiving/tag-library/3.0/n-b8e0.html) in the [National Library of Medicine Tag Set](http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/archiving/) (although I've never seen them used in over a million documents). Note that they include an `IDREF` attribute on the `milestone-end` to pair it with a `milestone-start/@id`. This will definitely help in dealing with these elements while you're parsing.

Expanding on the OSIS comment, because I found this particularly interesting and elegant (or at least as elegant a solution as one can have for this messy problem), from [this article](http://xml.coverpages.org/DeRoseEML2004.pdf):

> The solution used in OSIS is this: use neither a generic milestone tag nor specific extra ones, but instead use the very same tag as milestone and non-milestone elements: in empty and non-empty XML forms. A sighran through the group. In short,
>
> - Use `<q who='paris'>...</q>` when you can, otherwise
> - use `<q who='paris' sID='foo'/>...<q eID='foo'/>`
>
> This approach, which after Troy is called "Trojan milestones", comes nearly for free with typical schema languages. No extra elements are needed. One need only add sID and eID attributes, and ensure that empty content is permitted. Ergo not any elements fail to be milestonable at will or at need. The proper attributes come automatically because the same declaration is in effect.

Comment: I found another precedent I think, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Scripture_Information_Standard.  "OSIS gives particular attention to encoding overlapping markup, because Bibles exhibit such markup frequently, for example verses crossing paragraph boundaries and vice versa. "